# How to undo the code that has already been pushed to github

Tags: github, branch

Is there possible to undo the code that have been pushed to github? I want to push it to another branch, unfortunately the code instead goes to old branch.

Answer (score 0):

First, [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) your commit first onto the correct local branch, and push this one.

Then:

- If you are the only one working on that repository, you can `reset --hard` your local old branch, and `git push --force` it.
- Or you can simply revert your old branch last commit ([`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)), and push that new commit, which will cancel the code changes previously push to that branch.